# css, center div while having fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have two divs: menu and content. Menu is fixed on the left, and content is centered. The problem is that with lower screen resolutions, **the menu overlaps the content**.
Here's some css:

```
#content {
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu {
    z-index: 20;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

So, basically, I want the content to be centered with a left minimum of x px.
Is there an easy solution for that?

Comment: I suggest you put up a jsbin/jsfiddle so people can show you on your own html how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set up a Wrapper div parent to the content div... and give the wrapper margin-left: 100px; or however much you want.. simple as that

Answer (score 0):

you could use min-width
That should be the easiest solution. Otherwise post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can review it